# Protocol emailing R Package creators

Tags: research-process, code

I have found an R Package written up that does exactly what is required but cannot figure out a bug that has presented itself. I have gone through the code and source code for the function and cannot figure out the problem. The authors' emails were included in the documentation. Is it inappropriate to email the creators to ask if the bug has occurred before or if I have any faults in my arguments?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not specific to academia and pertains to everybody using this software. It **may** be on-topic on [Software Engineering](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/) or [stats.se].

Comment: As a user of such packages I often find that these packages are usually written In the academic world. But as a user od Cross Validated is not on topic there.

Comment: Ask your question [the smart way](http://www.catb.org/esr/faqs/smart-questions.html) and I think you'll be fine.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming that the documentation does not explicitly tell you not to email the maintainers about bugs, and assuming that there's not a forum, bug-tracker, etc. for the package, then I think it would be perfectly reasonable to contact one of them via the email address they provide in the documentation.

If they provide no other means of reporting bugs in the package, then I don't think they'd have any justification for taking offence at being contacted at an address they provide alongside the package.

Comment: Is there a specific place I should first search for a bug tracker? Would it be included in the package doc? Additionally I see the package lists a 'maintainer', I assume this would be the point of contact? Thanks for the advice @Ian_Fin

Comment: I'd assume that if it exists then it'll be mentioned in the documentation. If not, you could try Googling the package. Which package is it?

Comment: But yeah, if you find no indication that there's a bug tracker or relevant forum then the maintainer would be the first point of contact.

Comment: Physical Activity: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/PhysicalActivity/PhysicalActivity.pdf

Comment: @MB_analyst I would contact Leena Choi, and, as Jack St. Claire, points out, make sure to include as much relevant information as you can about the problem.

Answer (score 3):

I assume they want to put out a good product.

I email technical book authors when I find errors. The programmers include their emails for a reason, one is to let them know you found a problem.

Try to reproduce the error, screenshot it, attach the screenshot, add the script you ran, and add a short paragraph about what happened.

Comment: Don't screen shot it. Attach a minimal working example of executable R script code. Programmers should have to transcribe your code from a screen shot. Code is where they live, and it's what they want when you find a bug. You should also attach any text messages that demonstrate the error if R gives one.

Comment: That's true. I don't know why I forgot to say add the code. I added it to the answer. Since this R, I'd still attach a screenshot since the error might be data-dependent and the authors definitely don't want the data. I've also seen OS dependent errors in certain Python packages that the author might struggle to reproduce. I don't know if R could have that same issue

Answer (score 0):

Why else would they put their email there, if not so that people can email them about bugs?

Of course you can email them. There is no protocol, besides the typical bug report conventions:

- Short and to the point
- Subject line clearly indicates it's a bug in so-and-so package
- Gives steps to reproduce bug, also provides a minimal example if possible
- Says exactly which version, platform, etc. you found the bug on

However, often people are busy, and may not have time to answer your email. It may be months before you get a reply, or you might never get it. You would have better luck on a forum or site like StackOverflow, where other users who have found workarounds might go. If the package author cares about supporting users, he will be checking these sites anyway.